# IOS - Log in to facebook on safari using token from FBSession

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, safari, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm working on an ios app in which the user is logged in to facebook using the facebook iOS SDK. The authentication is made using the the username/password the user has entered in the facebook app. It works perfectly.

Now I would like to open a facebook page in Safari (or a uiwebview within the app, but let's just say safari for now).

Here's a basic example:

> NSURL * targetUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://m.facebook.com"];
>
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:targetUrl];

Every time I open the page, the user has to enter his login/password again.
I don't want to open the page in the facebook app.
Is there a way to **pass the FB token somewhere** so that the user is automatically authenticated in safari when the facebook website is open?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem? I have the same issue